# Seaborn displot / KDE plot

Tags: matplotlib, graph, seaborn

How can I make a multipanel plot with

seaborn
sns.kdeplot()
the kdeplot function has a hue parameter but no col, row to separate the graphs

Seaborn
sns.displot()
the displot function seems to have the kind='kde' parameter but you can't change the bandwidth on it.

Is there any way to do a multi panel plot with kdeplots or add bandwidth to displot() on seaborn?

Comment: You can pass the same parameters to `displot` as to `kdeplot`. `displot` will take care to pass these parameters to the correct function, depending on `kind=...`.

Comment: oh got it thanks. I was getting errors cause I was trying to pass bw into displot but bw only works with kdeplot because it is deprecated.